# Dojox/mobile/scrollableview scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dojo, dojox.mobile

dojox/mobile/ScrollableView (1.10+) in a cordova application have some scroll issues, which I have started observing recently and its only happening in android phones. I am currently using widget-based architecture. Even some of the store apps are facing this issue. Please suggest/help in resolving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did u find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: I had raised a ticket. no outcome. https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18964

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent problem introduced by latest release of **Android System WebView** of 2016 Dec 9 (v 55.0.2883.91)

The only work-around I know is to go to Settings->Apps and uninstall this version (it will be replaced with the initial version, in my case I have WebView 43.0.2357.121).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any quick fix for this other than the one which you suggested?

Comment: Did you check your current version of WebView? If you have v55.0.2883.91 the quick fix is the one I already provided (and tested). Or wait for a newer version (v56.0.2924 is still in beta, not tested). Or stop using Dojo, as many people is doing...

Comment: My device is on latest 80.x WebView version, still I see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing dojo.js file in project with old dojo.js here 
https://github.com/manjunath143/DOJO_SCROLL/blob/master/dojo.js helped me to resolve scrolling issue